# return value after run another AsyncTask in onPostExecute()

Tags: android, android-asynctask

How to return value to main activity after run another AsyncTask in onPostExecute()?

I have written function in 2nd Asynctask to return ArrayList back to 1st Asynctask. However, I don't know how to return the ArrayList from 1st Asynctask back to main activity.

```
//Main Activity:
DownloaderGet downloaderGet = new DownloaderGet(getActivity(), "http://xxxxx.php");
downloaderGet.execute();

//1st AsyncTask(DownloaderGet)
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String jsonData) {
        super.onPostExecute(jsonData);
        new DataParserGet(c, jsonData).execute();
    }

//2nd Asynctask(DataParserGet)
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        pd.dismiss();
        if(result)
        {
            myNewArrayList = spacecrafts;
            passToClass();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem:** You want to pass the array list from the second AsyncTask back to MainActivity.

**Solution:** Passing activity instance to the first AsyncTask, then forward the instance to the second AsyncTask.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Pass `this` as activity instance to the first AsyncTask.
        DownloaderGet downloaderGet = new DownloaderGet(this, "http://xxxxx.php");
        downloaderGet.execute();
    }

    public void onDataAvailable(List<String> arrauList) {
        // Process array list here.

    }
}

// The first AsyncTask.
class DownloaderGet extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    private WeakReference<MainActivity> activity;
    private String url;

    DownloaderGet(MainActivity activity, String url) {
        this.activity = new WeakReference<>(activity);
        this.url = url;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        // Your code here
        // ...
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String jsonData) {
        // Forward the instance to the second AsyncTask.
        new DataParserGet(activity.get(), jsonData).execute();
    }
}

class DataParserGet extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
    private WeakReference<MainActivity> activity;
    private String jsonData;

    DataParserGet(MainActivity activity, String jsonData) {
        this.activity = new WeakReference<>(activity);
        this.jsonData = jsonData;
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        // Your code here
        // ...
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        if (result) {
            myNewArrayList = spacecrafts;
            if (activity.get() != null) {
                // Pass the array list back to main activity.
                activity.get().onDataAvailable(myNewArrayList);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this following those steps

Create an `interface`

```
public interface AsyncResponse {
  void passToClass(Boolean output);
}
```

You can change the parameter of passToClass() as you wish.

Declare an instance of `AsyncResponse` in your AsyncTask

```
public AsyncResponse delegate = null;
```

In `onPostExecute`

```
delegate.passToClass(result);
```

Then make you `Activity` implement `AsyncResponse`

```
public class MainActivity implements AsyncResponse
```

Finally override your method and get get your result in your `Activity`

```
@Override
void passToClass(Boolean output){
 //here you get the reuslt from AsyncTask
}
```

Comment: By doing this way, am I going to pass the result straight to my main activity, without passing it back to 1st asynctask right? Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Have you tried it ? If I get you right, no you will have the result in your main activity only when it's set in the AsyncTask

Answer (score 0):

> Asynctask is used to run long running operations.

If you are already using one asynctask, you don't need another asynctask. Try putting all that second asynctask code inside the first.

```
public void doInBackground(){

  //Sample1

  //Dependent code waiting for sample1 to finish

}
```

You can wait for some code to finish that you can input to another piece of code, everything inside only one asynctask.

To return some code to MainActivity from asynctask, use callback using interface.

> 1. Create interface

```
public interface MyTaskCallback{
  void myResultData();
}
```

> 2. Implement interface in destination. In your case, MainActivity is the destination.

```
public void MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MyTaskCallback{



   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //Start the task. Pass interface reference in the constructor of the task
    new MyTask(MainActivity.this).execute();
   }
}
```

> 3. Pass reference of interface to the AsyncTask Constructor from Activity

```
public void MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

   private MyTaskCallback myTaskCallback;

   public MyTask(myTaskCallback){
     this.myTaskCallback = myTaskCallback;
   }

   public void onPostExecute(){
     if(myTaskCallback != null)
        myTaskCallback.myResultData();
   }

}
```